# Graphical Simulators (Simulink) vs traditional mathematical languages (MATLAB, Python)

Tags: dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling, simulink

I want to specifically create models for large biological systems involving partial differential equations(diffusion equation) as well as using ODE's etc.

I'm still and undergraduate student so this is ultimately my goal. Still learning all the basics.

I currently use python to generate and solve as well as display the basic dynamic models. However, this textbook I stumbled upon uses these graphical methods such as Simulink. I see Maple also has an alternative to this as well as Scilab.

For the field I want to go into, would you recommend going the way of suing these graphical simulators and why? Which would you recommend as well?

Comment: I personally prefer MATLAB for anything that is not symbolic. There is something called "PDE toolbox," which is an add-on for MATLAB, that basically gives MATLAB finite-element capabilities. Since you said your systems were "large" (I assume this means "requires extensive computation"), this is a good option. For ODEs there is also of course the classic "ode45" numerical solver in MATLAB among others, which I have had (mostly) good experiences with. This is not to discourage any other programs, this is just my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For mathematical modelling I use Mathematica. It has many built in ODE solvers and ways of graphically representing solutions.